# calling a custom S3 method

Tags: r, class, methods

I'm asked to assign class TonnageData to an object Froud which is a data frame with info about ships. Then I have to write a C3 method for the new class.
The class is assigned to the object:

```
  class(Froud)
[1] "TonnageData"
```

I have the method written (has to calculate mean and sd for Tonnage column by Power type):

```
 stats.TonnageData <- function(frd){
list(mean = by(frd$Tonnage, frd$Power, mean), standard_deviation = by(frd$Tonnage, frd$Power, sd))}
```

It calculates what I want, but when I call the method for my object this way:

```
 stats(Froud)
```

I get:

```
 Error in stats(Froud) : could not find function "stats"
```

It only works when given together with the class:

```
 stats.TonnageData(Froud)
```

Why is it? I did another exercise just last week where class and method were written the exact same way and the method works when called on its own.

Comment: My guess is that the exercise last week involved an already existing generic function, which `stats` is not.

Comment: yep, that was it. That was half hour banging my head on the wall well spent